# NSDateFormatter returning nil for some objects only

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm a little confused with NSDateFormatter. I have this code:

```
NSDate *createdDate = [fav objectForKey:@"created_at"];

NSString *b = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:createdDate
                                             dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                             timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

NSString *c = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                             dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                             timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

The string c works fine but the string b is nil.

I printed both NSDate objects and they have a small difference:

```
[NSDate date] returns 2014-07-21 16:54:31 +0000
createdDate returns 2014-07-14T12:41:57.755-05:00
```

What's happening?

Comment: Your `createdDate` is a *string* (`NSString` object) and not a `NSDate`. Therefore `localizedStringFromDate:...` returns `nil`.

Comment: You have an NSDate reference pointing to an NSString. Don't do that.

Comment: `localizedStringFromDate` is not a (legal) method on iOS.  And the two dates you show above are entirely different formats.  The first appears to be an NSDate `description` dump.  The second isn't.

Comment: Why are people down voting the question? It includes all of the appropriate code and it includes the needed output to diagnose the issue. What more do you want?

Comment: So... what should I do? (btw, thank you rmaddy)

Comment: You have date string. Convert that to an `NSDate` then you can use the code you have to convert the `NSDate` to the new string format.

Comment: oh ok... thank you :) could you please put it as an answer to accept it? you were the only one who came to actually help instead of complain

Comment: @user3423369 Actually the very first comment was helpful and told you the problem up front.

Comment: you're right... thank you Martin R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set The Format before you pass the date

```
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[formatter stringFromDate:YourDate];
```

with this you have a string from  date

hope it works for you

Comment: Specifically I found that the format I had to use was "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" because of the time zone and the milliseconds...